# Can't access HttpSession in Spring MVC @Controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

I have a controller class in Spring MVC project. My code is like below:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/doLogin")
public String login(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("pwd") String password, Model model){
   //some code
  }
}
```

I want to pass HttpSession as method parameter but I'm not able to access HttpSession. I've attached a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If solved then you can also accept my answer for fellow **SO** users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't have servlet api dependency in your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get your `HttpSession` from `HttpServletRequest`. `req.getSession(false)` returns a `HttpSession` object if already created,if not then `null` returned. `req.getSession(true)` check if no session created, then returned a new one instead of `null`.
N.B: Also make your that [javax servlet api](https://maven-eu.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.0.1/servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) jar added to your class path.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/doLogin")
public String login(
    HttpServletRequest req, 
    @RequestParam("email") String email,
    @RequestParam("pwd") String password, 
    Model model
){
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
   //some code
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not my actual problem. I couldn't use HttpSession even inside of any method. I've solved this problem after importing javax.servlet jar library

Comment: I also said it in last line (N.B) btw. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `java servlet` in your project. Add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just posted it before seeing your post !

Comment: You can compare time :) My answer was posted before yours

Comment: What's the matter ? I just told you that yes you posted it before it's just when I was writting the answer. I didn't see your post !